# How to adjust sp.signal.spectrogram so that the x-axis starts at 0?

Tags: python, scipy, spectrogram

I am plotting a spectrogram of a time-series `data` with a sampling rate of 2.16 seconds using `scipy.signal.spectrogram`.

My problem is that the x-axis of the plot `plt.pcolormesh(time, freq, spec, shading="gouraud")` does not start at `0`, but instead at `22.68`, and then the x-axis goes up to `63.72`.

I understand that the x-axis range, printable via `print(time)`, depends on the `nperseg` value of `scipy.signal.spectrogram`. Hence, the `nperseg` value determines the possible output or range of the x-axis by `scipy.signal.spectrogram`.

However, isn't there a way to plot the spectrogram so that the x-axis starts at 0, since the time-series `data` starts at 0 or 1 with a first data point in time?
Here is a full and reproducible code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data of time-series
data = [1.577914, -4.299067, 1.994959, 1.006487, -3.092386, 2.552159, 0.270319,
        -0.406156, 2.364457, -2.212027, -0.985193, -2.660199, 4.171447, 1.508614,
        0.710774, 0.62389, 0.157947, 0.885811, 1.126204, 2.449504, -3.167271,
        -2.473564, -3.03687, 0.573946, 1.123078, -0.745824, -5.395092, -3.487601,
        -1.41748, 2.737564, 2.061715, -0.249747, 2.174746, 2.229604, -4.607001,
        2.951738, -1.859603, 3.03217, 0.87048, 1.842302, 5.207679, 0.3907389]
data = np.array(data)

# Spectrogram
freq, time, spec = sp.signal.spectrogram(data, fs=1/2.16,
                                         window=('tukey', 0.25),
                                         nperseg=21,
                                         noverlap=None, nfft=42,
                                         detrend=False,
                                         return_onesided=True,
                                         scaling="density",
                                         axis=-1, mode="psd")

# Plot
plt.pcolormesh(time, freq, spec, shading="gouraud")
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("Time [seconds]", fontweight="bold", fontsize=12)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.01, 0.24, 0.05), fontsize=12)
plt.ylim([0.01, 0.23])
plt.ylabel("Frequency [Hz]", fontweight="bold", fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

[image]